# Counting occurrence of string value in df1 if other column date value in df1 is between two dates in df2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, conditional-statements

```
    df1 = pandas.DataFrame( { 
        "ID" : ["11", "11", "11", "11"] , 
        "updated_date" : ["2019/04/03", "2019/05/02", "2019/05/20", "2019/03/03"],
        "other_date" : ["2019/04/09", "2019/05/14", "2019/06/05", "2019/03/07"] } )
    
    
    df2 = pandas.DataFrame( { 
        "ID" : ["11", "11", "11", "11"] , 
        "new_date" : ["2019/04/02", "2019/05/03", "2019/05/13", "2019/03/04"],
        "characteristic" : ["T", "T", "T", "T"] } )
```

I have two dataframes that look like those above with lots of different ID numbers (only using one as example). Id like to count how many 'new_dates' are between 'updated_date' and 'other_date' & characteristic = 'T' for each id number.

Example:

ID 11 has 4 date ranges in df_1. I would like to count every 'T' for when ID  = 11 & updated_date < new_date < other_date

```
    ID   |  updated_date |  other_date | 
0   11   |   2019-04-03  |  2019-04-09 | 
1   11   |   2019-05-02  |  2019-05-14 |
2   11   |   2019-05-20  |  2019-06-05 | 
3   11   |   2019-03-03  |  2019-03-07 | 


    ID   |    new date   |  characteristic  | 
0   11   |   2019-04-02  |         T        | 
1   11   |   2019-05-03  |         T        |
2   11   |   2019-05-13  |         T        | 
3   11   |   2019-03-04  |         P        |
```

Desired output

```
    ID   |  updated_date |  other_date | count_ts |
0   11   |   2019-04-03  |  2019-04-09 |    0     |
1   11   |   2019-05-02  |  2019-05-14 |    2     |
2   11   |   2019-05-20  |  2019-06-05 |    0     |
3   11   |   2019-03-03  |  2019-03-07 |    0     |
```

For row #0 there are 0 new_dates between updated_date and other_date. Therefore count_ts = 0

For row #1 there are 2x new_dates between updated_date and other_date  (2019-05-03 & 2019-05-13) and both have a T as the characteristic. Therefore count_ts = 2

For row #2 there are 0 new_dates between updated_date and other_date. Therefore count_ts = 0

For row #3 there is 1x new_dates between updated_date and other_date  (2019-03-04) but both characteristic is 'P' not 'T'. Therefore count_ts = 0

Answer (score 0):

1. **merge**:

   **df3=pd.merge(df1,df2,how='left',on='ID')**

then you got a new table:

```
ID  updated_date    other_date  new_date    characteristic
0   11  2019/04/03  2019/04/09  2019/04/02  T
1   11  2019/04/03  2019/04/09  2019/05/03  T
2   11  2019/04/03  2019/04/09  2019/05/13  T
3   11  2019/04/03  2019/04/09  2019/03/04  T
4   11  2019/05/02  2019/05/14  2019/04/02  T
5   11  2019/05/02  2019/05/14  2019/05/03  T
6   11  2019/05/02  2019/05/14  2019/05/13  T
7   11  2019/05/02  2019/05/14  2019/03/04  T
8   11  2019/05/20  2019/06/05  2019/04/02  T
9   11  2019/05/20  2019/06/05  2019/05/03  T
10  11  2019/05/20  2019/06/05  2019/05/13  T
11  11  2019/05/20  2019/06/05  2019/03/04  T
12  11  2019/03/03  2019/03/07  2019/04/02  T
13  11  2019/03/03  2019/03/07  2019/05/03  T
14  11  2019/03/03  2019/03/07  2019/05/13  T
15  11  2019/03/03  2019/03/07  2019/03/04  T
```

2. **filter**:

**df4=df3[(df3['updated_date']<df3['new_date']) & (df3['new_date']<df3['other_date'])]**

```
ID  updated_date    other_date  new_date    characteristic
5   11  2019/05/02  2019/05/14  2019/05/03  T
6   11  2019/05/02  2019/05/14  2019/05/13  T
15  11  2019/03/03  2019/03/07  2019/03/04  T
```

3. **group_by**:you can use group by or pivot table. Both are the same. I prefer pivot:

**df4.pivot_table(index=['ID','updated_date','other_date'],columns=['characteristic'],values=['characteristic'],aggfunc='count').droplevel(0,axis=1)**

```
characteristic  T   p
ID  updated_date    other_date      
11  2019/03/03  2019/03/07  NaN 1.0
    2019/05/02  2019/05/14  2.0 NaN
```

please note that this is a general approach. for your specification, you should add filter condition in STEP 2.

Comment: this is good but not quite the answer I was looking for. See the desired output and notice that we only want to count 'T's not 'P's

Comment: Just add a filter condition in the step TWO!

Comment: This still was not what I am looking for. I am looking for a count per date range not just per ID. Looking for exactly what I put in the desired output @balalala